# When I use form in html I lose searcher css animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm new and I'm discovering web design & development.

I have a little problem when I put a form in html, I don't know what is hapenning with the searcher css animation.

The Html Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Buscador de Súper Héroes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="principal-container">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Búsqueda de<br/>Superhéroe</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="buscar">
            <form action="busqueda.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="busqueda" class="buscar_texto" placeholder="Ej: spiderman, hulk, ironman">
                <button type="submit" class="boton"><i class="icon-buscar"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you remove `<form></form>` you can see the css animation in the seracher.

And the CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap');
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url(bg1.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
}

.principal-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.title{
    font-family: "Anton";
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    width: 100vw;
}

h1 {
    background-image: url(https://media4.giphy.com/media/FTSF0BjxZIFEs/giphy.gif);
    background-size: cover;
    color: transparent;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 180px;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 10px 0;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}

.buscar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #131313;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
}

.buscar_texto{
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    color: rgba(255, 196, 0, 0.5);
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 60px;
    transition: .3s;
    width: 0;
}

.button{
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
}

.boton{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(255, 196, 0, 0.5);
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

For the icon styles.css (fontastic.me)

```
@charset "UTF-8";

@font-face {
  font-family: "buscar";
  src:url("fonts/buscar.eot");
  src:url("fonts/buscar.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("fonts/buscar.woff") format("woff"),
    url("fonts/buscar.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("fonts/buscar.svg#buscar") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

}

[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: "buscar" !important;
  content: attr(data-icon);
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: "buscar" !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-buscar:before {
  content: "\61";
}
```

That is all. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: I think your viewport should be the first thing in your `<head>`

Comment: But only once :)

Comment: There is two `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in code

Comment: @RayeesAC Thank you, i fixed it, but didn't solve my problem ;(

Comment: which icon you are using in here `icon-buscar`? it there is any cdn for it.

Comment: @LUISFELIPECORTAZARAGREDO  Can you see the animation over here(, I can): https://www.codeply.com/p/yyXQ1y2CXd

Comment: @koder613 Thanks, I mean the animation of the searcher.

Comment: @RayeesAC Oh, sorry about that, is the other css, edited in post.